# R-Code = mutate function along with case when = values are dynamic

Tags: r, dplyr

In the below code the value 147.45 and 13.2475 will keep on changing.  These value of average number of cases and average TAT.  TAT and Cases are variables.  Is there any way I can impute the average value of Cases and TAT in the below code so that I can avoid changing them manually each time.

```
library(dplyr)

LT10LC%>% 
  mutate(Class = case_when(Cases > 147.45  & TAT > 13.2475 ~"Horse",
                           Cases <= 147.45 & TAT > 13.2475 ~ "Duck", 
                           Cases <= 147.45 & TAT <= 13.2475 ~ "Sheep",
                           TRUE ~ "Tiger"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can precalculate mean in a variable and use it in `case_when` :

```
library(dplyr)

LT10LC %>% 
  mutate(mean_case = mean(Cases, na.rm = TRUE), mean_tat = mean(TAT, na.rm = TRUE),
         Class = case_when(Cases > mean_case  & TAT > mean_tat ~"Horse",
                           Cases <= mean_case & TAT > mean_tat ~ "Duck", 
                           Cases <= mean_case & TAT <= mean_tat ~ "Sheep", 
                           TRUE ~ "Tiger"))
```